# $E[X^4]\ge(E[X^2])^2$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I came across a true/false question that had $$E[X^4]\ge(E[X^2])^2$$
marked as TRUE. When I work it out it seems inconclusive. Can anyone explain? Thanks!

Comment: Note that $E[X^4]-(E[X^2])^2=\operatorname{Var}(X^2)$. The variance of a random variable is always a non-negative real number.

Comment: If $X\in L_4(P)$, with $P$ a probability measure, then by Holder's inequality or Cauchy-Schwartx inequality $E[X^2]=E[X^2\mathbb{1}]\leq( E[X^4])^{1/2}(E[\mathbb{1}^2])^{1/2}=(E[X^4])^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true. It's a consequence of Jensen's inequality. You might have already seen that
$$E[Y]^2\le E[Y^2]$$

Just apply the latter with $Y=X^2$.

Comment: I can see that now. But I still don't see how it works with actually working out the expected values, i.e. $E[X^2]=x_1^2p_1+x_2^2p_2+x_3^2p_3+...$

Comment: There are many ways to prove it. You can use for instance Jensen's inequality, which states that for any convex function $\varphi$ and real numbers $\lambda_i\ge0$ such that $\sum_i\lambda_i=1$, we have $\varphi(\sum_i\lambda_iy_i)\le\sum_i\lambda_i\varphi(y_i)$. Apply the latter with $\varphi(x)=x^2$, $\lambda_i=p_i$ and $y_i=x_i^2$.

Comment: I think that's beyond the scope of my current course and knowledge. Maybe I'll get there someday... Thanks! BTW which type of course would teach Jensen's inequality?

Comment: Any introduction to measure and integration theory should mention Jensen's inequality, I suppose. But if it's beyond the scope of your course, no worries, there are other ways to see it. As other people pointed out, you can just expand $0\le E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2]-2E[X]^2+E[X]^2=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$, hence $E[X]^2\le E[X^2]$.

Comment: I haven't had an introduction to measure and integration theory. This is just a statistics class. I get that with the $Y=X^2$ substitution you can use the fact that $0 \leq Var(Y)=E[Y^2]-(E[Y])^2$, but where are you getting the $0 \leq E[(X-E[X])^2]$? I suppose what I'm mostly wondering about is expanding it out based on the definition of expected value in the discrete case, i.e. $E[X^2]=x_1^2p_1+x_2^2p_2+...$.

Comment: Oh I see that $E[(X-E[X])^2]$ is also the variance.

Comment: The expected value is a linear operator, which means that $E[aX+b]=aE[X]+b$. This is how you can easily prove that $Var(X)=E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$. Moreover, the fact that $E[(X-E[X])^2]\ge0$ uses another property of the expected value, that for any NONNEGATIVE random variable $Y$, $E[Y]\ge0$. Here we have the expected value of $(E-E[X])^2$, which is of course nonnegative since it is the square of something.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\alpha^2 \equiv E(X^2]$$
Then
$$ E[ (X^2-\alpha^2)^2] = E[X^4]-2\alpha^2E[X^2] +   \alpha^4 \\=E[X^4] - \alpha^4$$

The result follows because $(X^2-\alpha^2)^2 \ge 0$